# Image Slideshow Swift ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to ios development. I am trying to make a simple fullscreen image slide show. On swipe left, the slideshow should show the next image, and swipe right the slideshow should show the previous image.

I have it working, however, if I swipe in quick succession, I get a blank screen, almost as if the animations aren't keeping up, and then when I wait a moment and swipe again the image views speed up into place and works normally again. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? What is the best practice when it comes to implementing an image carousel like this with a dynamic amount of images (here they're hardcoded)?

```
import UIKit

var imageArr = ["imageOne.jpg", "imageTwo.jpg", "imageThree.jpg", "imageFour.jpg", "imageFive.jpg"]
var imageIndex = 0;

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var currImage = UIImageView()
    var rightImage = UIImageView()
    var leftImage = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var bounds:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var width:CGFloat = bounds.size.width
        var height:CGFloat = bounds.size.height


        currImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
        currImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArr[imageIndex])

        rightImage.frame = CGRect(x: width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
        rightImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArr[imageIndex + 1])

        leftImage.frame = CGRect(x: -width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
        leftImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArr[imageArr.count - 1])

        self.view.addSubview(currImage)
        self.view.addSubview(rightImage)
        self.view.addSubview(leftImage)

        var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    let transitionManager = TransitionManager()


    func handleSwipe(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        var bounds:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var width:CGFloat = bounds.size.width
        var height:CGFloat = bounds.size.height

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

            if (swipeGesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left ) {

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {


                    self.currImage.frame = CGRect(x: -width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
                    self.rightImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width: width, height: height)

                    }, completion: { finished in

                        if (!finished) { return }

                        imageIndex++
                        imageIndex = imageIndex <= imageArr.count-1 ? imageIndex : 0

                        var leftIndex = imageIndex - 1 < 0 ? imageArr.count - 1 : imageIndex - 1

                        self.leftImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArr[leftIndex])
                        self.leftImage.frame = CGRect(x: -width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)

                        var tempImg = self.currImage

                        self.currImage = self.rightImage

                        self.rightImage = tempImg

                        self.rightImage.frame = CGRect(x: width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)

                        var rightIndex = imageIndex + 1 > imageArr.count - 1 ? 0 : imageIndex + 1
                        self.rightImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArr[rightIndex])

                })
            }

            if (swipeGesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right) {


                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

                    self.currImage.frame = CGRect(x: width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
                    self.leftImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)

                    }, completion: { finished in


                        imageIndex--
                        imageIndex = imageIndex < 0 ? imageArr.count - 1 : imageIndex

                        var rightIndex = imageIndex + 1 > imageArr.count - 1 ? 0 : imageIndex + 1

                        self.rightImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArr[rightIndex])
                        self.rightImage.frame = CGRect(x: width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)

                        var tempImg = self.currImage

                        self.currImage = self.tempImg
                        self.leftImage = tempCurr

                        self.leftImage.frame = CGRect(x: -width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
                        var leftIndex = imageIndex - 1 < 0 ? imageArr.count - 1 : imageIndex - 1
                        self.leftImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArr[leftIndex])

                })
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: On this line: self.leftImage = tempCurr   what is tempCurr? There's a compile error.

Comment: I figured it out:                   `var tempImg = self.currImage
                        self.currImage = self.leftImage
                        self.leftImage = tempImg`

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView:UIImageView!

var i=Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(imageChange), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@objc func imageChange(){
    self.imageView.image=images[i]
    if i<images.count-1{
        i+=1
    }
    else{
        i=0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried CollectionView for the carousel slideshow, but it didn't work out for me. I didn't like the hackish ways I had to do to make it show images in one row and I also didn't like the fact that it cannot return the active image (there is some workaround here as well, but they don't seem reliable). So, naturally, I ended up building a custom slideshow carousel for my purpose. I will share the code here, so hopefully, it can help(or at least guide someone) with a similar problem.

NOTE: My carousel is full width, singleImagePerScreen carousel, with a swipe recognizer to swipe through images and delegate function that is triggered when an image is active(I use it to display active image - "1 of 5").

TESTED ON: SWIFT 5, XCode 12.2, iOS 14.2

```
// ImageCarouselView class

import UIKit

class ImageCarouselView: UIView {
    private let images: [UIImage?]
    private var index = 0
    private let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    var delegate: ImageCarouselViewDelegate?

    lazy var previousImageView = imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
    lazy var currentImageView = imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
    lazy var nextImageView = imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)

    lazy var previousImageLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return previousImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: -screenWidth)
    }()

    lazy var currentImageLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return currentImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
    }()

    lazy var nextImageLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return nextImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: screenWidth)
    }()

    init(_ images: [UIImage?]) {
        self.images = images

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        setupLayout()
        setupImages()
        setupSwipeRecognizer()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        self.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

        addSubview(previousImageView)
        addSubview(currentImageView)
        addSubview(nextImageView)

        previousImageLeadingConstraint = previousImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: -screenWidth)
        currentImageLeadingConstraint = currentImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
        nextImageLeadingConstraint = nextImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: screenWidth)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            previousImageLeadingConstraint,
            previousImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            previousImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth),

            currentImageLeadingConstraint,
            currentImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            currentImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth),

            nextImageLeadingConstraint,
            nextImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            nextImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth),
        ])
    }

    private func setupImages() {
        currentImageView.image = images[self.index]

        guard images.count > 1 else { return }

        if (index == 0) {
            previousImageView.image = images[images.count - 1]
            nextImageView.image = images[index + 1]
        }

        if (index == (images.count - 1)) {
            previousImageView.image = images[index - 1]
            nextImageView.image = images[0]
        }
    }

    private func setupSwipeRecognizer() {
        guard images.count > 1 else { return }

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        self.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    @objc private func handleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.direction == .left) {
            showNextImage()
        }

        if (sender.direction == .right) {
            showPreviousImage()
        }
    }

    private func showPreviousImage() {
        previousImageLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
        currentImageLeadingConstraint.constant = screenWidth

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.nextImageView = self.currentImageView
            self.currentImageView = self.previousImageView
            self.previousImageView = self.imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)

            self.index = self.index == 0 ? self.images.count - 1 : self.index - 1
            self.delegate?.imageCarouselView(self, didShowImageAt: self.index)
            self.previousImageView.image = self.index == 0 ? self.images[self.images.count - 1] : self.images[self.index - 1]

            self.setupLayout()
        })
    }

    private func showNextImage() {
        nextImageLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
        currentImageLeadingConstraint.constant = -screenWidth

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.previousImageView = self.currentImageView
            self.currentImageView = self.nextImageView
            self.nextImageView = self.imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)

            self.index = self.index == (self.images.count - 1) ? 0 : self.index + 1
            self.delegate?.imageCarouselView(self, didShowImageAt: self.index)
            self.nextImageView.image = self.index == (self.images.count - 1) ? self.images[0] : self.images[self.index + 1]

            self.setupLayout()
        })
    }

    func imageView(image: UIImage? = nil, contentMode: UIImageView.ContentMode) -> UIImageView {
        let view = UIImageView()

        view.image = image
        view.contentMode = contentMode
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return view
    }
}

// ImageCarouselViewDelegate

import UIKit

protocol ImageCarouselViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func imageCarouselView(_ imageCarouselView: ImageCarouselView, didShowImageAt index: Int)
}

// Usage

let slideshowView = ImageCarouselView(images) // initialize

self.slideshowView.delegate = self // set delegate in viewDidLoad()

extension YourViewController: ImageCarouselViewDelegate {
    func imageCarouselView(_ imageCarouselView: ImageCarouselView, didShowImageAt index: Int) {
        // do something with index
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add collection view, add image in your custom collectionview cell, after that do **checked**  `Paging Enabled` on props panel for collectionview. Use timer for auto slide

[image: Collection view]

Comment: i am here because I thought this method would work. Bu in different screen sizes this method creates problems